# possible to define an array in Sass?

Tags: haml, sass

wondering if it is possible to use an array with Sass as I find my self repeating the following sort of thing:

```
.donkey
  h2
    background-color= !donkey

.giraffe
  h2
    background-color= !giraffe

.iguana
  h2
    background-color= !iguana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The best way to do it is to define a mixin:

```
+animal-h2(!name, !color)
  .#{name} h2
    background-color= !color
```

Then you can have one line per style, rather than three:

```
+animal-h2("donkey", !donkey)
+animal-h2("giraffe", !giraffe)
+animal-h2("iguana", !iguana)
```

Answer (score 18):

Absolutely.

```
$animals: "donkey", "giraffe", "iguana"
@foreach $animal in $animals
  .#{$animal}
    h2
      background-color: !#{$animal}
```

Comment: Justin is right on this. I've used [Sass lists](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#lists) for fun and profit and can vouch for their usefulness. After reading up on Sass lists, you should also take a look at Sass's list functions, found [here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#list-functions). They're almost never helpful, but they can really make your life easier in certain instances!

Answer (score 0):

nex3's answer is correct.  To get this working with SASS on Rails 3.1 I needed to have the following in a css.scss file:

```
$donkey: #CC4499;

@mixin animal-h2($name, $color) {
  .#{$name} h2 {
    background-color: $color;
  }
}

@include animal-h2("donkey", $donkey);
@include animal-h2("horse", #000);
```

Which output:

```
.donkey h2 {
    background-color: #CC4499;
}

.horse h2 {
    background-color: black;
}
```